# Is pimpl compatible with anonymous namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces, pimpl-idiom

I am trying to use the **pimpl** pattern and define the implementation class in an anonymous namespace. Is this possible in C++? My failed attempt is described below.

Is it possible to fix this without moving the implementation into a namespace with a name (or the global one)?

```
class MyCalculatorImplementation;

class MyCalculator
{
public:
    MyCalculator();
    int CalculateStuff(int);

private:
    MyCalculatorImplementation* pimpl;
};

namespace // If i omit the namespace, everything is OK
{
    class MyCalculatorImplementation
    {
    public:
        int Calculate(int input)
        {
            // Insert some complicated calculation here
        }

    private:
        int state[100];
    };
}

// error C2872: 'MyCalculatorImplementation' : ambiguous symbol
MyCalculator::MyCalculator(): pimpl(new MyCalculatorImplementation)
{
}

int MyCalculator::CalculateStuff(int x)
{
    return pimpl->Calculate(x);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the type must be at least declared before the pointer type can be used, and putting anonymous namespace in the header won't really work. But why would you want to do that, anyway? If you really really want to hide the implementation class, make it a private inner class, i.e.

```
// .hpp
struct Foo {
    Foo();
    // ...
private:
    struct FooImpl;
    boost::scoped_ptr<FooImpl> pimpl;
};

// .cpp
struct Foo::FooImpl {
    FooImpl();
    // ...
};

Foo::Foo() : pimpl(new FooImpl) { }
```

Comment: This is what I used for the longest time, too, until someone pointed out to me that if you export class `Foo`, it also exports class `Foo::FooImpl`, and that's usually not what you want...

Comment: @mmutz Does _export_ mean the MS-related `__declspec(dllexport)`? If yes, i probably don't need to worry.

Comment: @anatolyg: yes, or `__attribute__((visibility=default))` on GCC/ELF systems.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is a work around for this.  Declare the pointer in the header file as void*, then use a reinterpret cast inside your implementation file.

**Note:** Whether this is a desirable work-around is another question altogether.  As is often said, I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.

See a sample implementation below:

```
class MyCalculator 
{
public:
    MyCalculator();
    int CalculateStuff(int);

private:
    void* pimpl;
};

namespace // If i omit the namespace, everything is OK
{
    class MyCalculatorImplementation
    {
    public:
        int Calculate(int input)
        {
            // Insert some complicated calculation here
        }

    private:
        int state[100];
    };
}

MyCalculator::MyCalculator(): pimpl(new MyCalculatorImplementation)
{
}

MyCalaculator::~MyCalaculator() 
{
    // don't forget to cast back for destruction!
    delete reinterpret_cast<MyCalculatorImplementation*>(pimpl);
}

int MyCalculator::CalculateStuff(int x)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<MyCalculatorImplementation*>(pimpl)->Calculate(x);
}
```

Comment: I think classical pimpl wouldn't be so popular, if `reinterpret_cast` actually was necessary. This clearly is not the way to go...

Comment: @m8mble To be clear, the question posed wasn't whether it was _advisable_; the question was whether it was _possible_.  As posed above, it is definitely possible, despite the other answers to the contrary.

Comment: @m8mbl  Your question of whether it is necessary is another question altogether.  And so a down-vote here seems a little much.  The post is still informative and offers a workaround that might be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. You have to forward-declare the Pimpl class:

```
class MyCalculatorImplementation;
```

and that declares the class. If you then put the definition into the unnamed namespace, you are creating another class `(anonymous namespace)::MyCalculatorImplementation`, which has nothing to do with `::MyCalculatorImplementation`.

If this was any other namespace `NS`, you could amend the forward-declaration to include the namespace:

```
namespace NS {
    class MyCalculatorImplementation;
}
```

but the unnamed namespace, being as magic as it is, will resolve to something else when that header is included into other translation units (you'd be declaring a new class whenever you include that header into another translation unit).

But use of the anonymous namespace is not needed here: the class declaration may be public, but the definition, being in the implementation file, is only visible to code in the implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want a forward declared class name in your header file and the implementation in an anonymous namespace in the module file, then make the declared class an interface:

```
// header
class MyCalculatorInterface;

class MyCalculator{
   ...
   MyCalculatorInterface* pimpl;
};



//module
class MyCalculatorInterface{
public:
    virtual int Calculate(int) = 0;
};

int MyCalculator::CalculateStuff(int x)
{
    return pimpl->Calculate(x);
}

namespace {
    class MyCalculatorImplementation: public MyCalculatorInterface {
        ...
    };
}

// Only the ctor needs to know about MyCalculatorImplementation
// in order to make a new one.
MyCalculator::MyCalculator(): pimpl(new MyCalculatorImplementation)
{
}
```

Comment: You'll still pollute the namespace of the public class with the `Interface` class -> no gain.

Answer (score 0):

markshiz and quamrana provided the inspiration for the solution below.

`class Implementation`, is intended to be declared in a global header file and serves as a `void*` for any pimpl application in your code base. It is not in an anonymous/unnamed namespace, but since it only has a destructor the namespace pollution remains acceptably limited.

`class MyCalculatorImplementation` derives from `class Implementation`. Because `pimpl` is declared as `std::unique_ptr<Implementation>` there is no need to mention `MyCalculatorImplementation` in any header file. So now `MyCalculatorImplementation` can be implemented in an anonymous/unnamed namespace.

The gain is that all member definitions in `MyCalculatorImplementation` are in the anonymous/unnamed namespace. The price you have to pay, is that you must convert `Implementation` to `MyCalculatorImplementation`. For that purpose a conversion function `toImpl()` is provided.
I was doubting whether to use a `dynamic_cast` or a `static_cast` for the conversion. I guess the `dynamic_cast` is the typical prescribed solution; but `static_cast` will work here as well and is possibly a little more performant.

```
#include <memory>

class Implementation
{
public:
  virtual ~Implementation() = 0;
};
inline Implementation::~Implementation() = default;

class MyCalculator
{
public:
  MyCalculator();
  int CalculateStuff(int);

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Implementation> pimpl;
};

namespace // Anonymous
{
class MyCalculatorImplementation
  : public Implementation
{
public:
  int Calculate(int input)
  {
    // Insert some complicated calculation here
  }

private:
  int state[100];
};

MyCalculatorImplementation& toImpl(Implementation& impl)
{
  return dynamic_cast<MyCalculatorImplementation&>(impl);
}
}

// no error C2872 anymore
MyCalculator::MyCalculator() : pimpl(std::make_unique<MyCalculatorImplementation>() )
{
}

int MyCalculator::CalculateStuff(int x)
{
  return toImpl(*pimpl).Calculate(x);
}
```